# Get /proc/<pid>/map info with sysctl call under mac os

Tags: c, macos, darwin, procfs, sysctl

I wanted to use `/proc/<pid>/map` directory in order to get info about virtual memory of a process (especially about its shared libraries). Since mac os doesn't have one I'm trying to find other ways. One of them seems to be `sysctl` call but I don't quite understand how to use it for such purpose. Are there any examples? I know it also can be done via some `mach_vm` interface calls but documentation is quite pour. Maybe you know any other ways of reading process memory? My mac os version is Darwin by the way.
Note: the purpose is to do this without using any utilities or `fork/exec` calls. I also don't want any `pseudofs` to be mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS' virtual memory subsystem is in the Mach-inherited part of the kernel, so those APIs are definitely the ones to use. For inspecting regions, look at `mach_vm_region()` (called `vm_region` in the original Mach - you will find [more documentation](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/vm_region.html) for that), for reading memory, use `mach_vm_read()`.

You may also find the `vmmap` command line utility to come in useful for exploration.

Comment: The problem really is that `mach_vm_region` can only tell that the region is shared but has no option to find which region stands for which shared library. I want the functionality similar to `vmmap -allStliptLibs`. Is it possible to get such without accessing the linker?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that. Even vmmap itself links against Symbolication.framework. The kernel holds a reference to the `vnode_t` somewhere internally, but as far as I'm aware there isn't even a public KPI for accessing that from a kext.